# Доступ к Room Database в MVVM

Tags: android, mvvm, room

В примере от Google [RecyclerViewFundamentals](https://github.com/google-developer-training/android-kotlin-fundamentals-apps/tree/master/RecyclerViewFundamentals) экземпляр DB мы получаем в "View" и передаем в ViewModel через ViewModelFactory:

```
class SleepTrackerFragment : Fragment() {
     ...
     val dataSource = SleepDatabase.getInstance(application).sleepDatabaseDao
     val viewModelFactory = SleepTrackerViewModelFactory(dataSource, application)
     val sleepTrackerViewModel =
            ViewModelProvider(
                    this, viewModelFactory).get(SleepTrackerViewModel::class.java)
     ...
}

class SleepTrackerViewModel(
    dataSource: SleepDatabaseDao,
    application: Application) : ViewModel() {

    val database = dataSource
    val nights = database.getAllNights()
}
```

Хотя паттерн MVVM предполагает доступ к "Model" во `ViewModel`. Помогите разобраться, можно ли создать `dataSource` во `ViewModel` или лучше использовать подход как в примере и почему?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это упрощённый пример + особенности платформы/библиотек.

Упрощённый, т.к. тут не используется DI (Toohpick, Dagger, Koin etc), который позволил бы получить все зависимости во ViewModel без их объявления во View.

Под особенностями платформы/библиотеки имеется в виду необходимость передачи Context в билдер БД. Context во ViewModel не доступен если не использовать DI или не прокинуть его туда вручную.

В принципе, т.к. во ViewModelFactory Context прокидывается и так, то можно сделать так, чтобы Dao создавался из БД не во врагменте, а там, где ViewModel создаётся, что убрало бы, отчасти, причину вашего вопроса, путём повышения субъективной сложности примера.